# How to use Switch statement to an access database in vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, switch-statement

I'm trying to *SELECT* the highest date value from 2 field as a variable then use it in *WHERE*
This is my query

```
SELECT Some_ID, Stuff_Name, Bla_number, Something_Else, SWITCH(Review_date > Revised_date, Review_date, Revised_date > Review_date, Revised_date) AS MaximumDate 
FROM DocList 
WHERE (MaximumDate >= CDATE('01/01/1990')) AND (MaximumDate <= CDATE('01/01/2011'))
```

I get the error No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: `CDATE('01/01/2011))` missing the closing tick

Comment: @Plutonix This was a typing. My code is not missing the closing tick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have another typo, or it doesn't know what MaximumDate is:

```
SELECT 
   Some_ID, 
   Stuff_Name, 
   Bla_number, 
   Something_Else, 
   DateAdd("yyyy", 2, IIf(Review_date > Revised_date, Review_date, Revised_date)) AS MaximumDate 
FROM 
   DocList 
WHERE 
   IIf(Review_date > Revised_date, Review_date, Revised_date)
       Between #01/01/1990# AND #01/01/2011#
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you for your answer! I wish I could give you a vote but I don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: Yeah, strange system. Thanks!

Comment: I also need to add 2 years to maximumDate. Any idea how I could do that?